# how does Git internally handle git push where no outstanding commits

Tags: git, caching, git-push, git-commit, git-remote

How does Git internally handle a `git push` for the case where the local branch is up-to-date with the remote , i.e. no outstanding commits ?

Does Git actually retrieve the latest state from the remote origin to determine that "Everything is up-to-date" --or-- does Git rely on its local cache of the remote origin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git push will check the ref from the remote server (via something similar to `git ls-remote` and get the hashes from there. If the hashes are the same as the one your branch has then it doesn't need to do anything else and thus will display that message.

Comment: thanks AlBlue - does `git status` also make a similar call to remote server ?

Comment: No, `git status` only checks your local workspace against changes you have added to the index in preparation for your next commit. It's an entirely local operation.